# Image doesn't show in image button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, embedded-resource, imageicon

I have create an image button but it didn’t show the image. The file is on `src\MyPackage` folder. How can I map it?

There is my code:

```
jpAnnotation=new JPanel();     

jpAnnotation.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JButton btnUnderline =new JButton(new ImageIcon ("UnderlineIcon.gif"));
btnUnderline.setSize(50, 260);
btnUnderline.setAlignmentX(JButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
btnUnderline.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.LEFT);
btnUnderline.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){                      
         ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(bean, 0, "Underline");
         bean.actionPerformed(ae);
    }
});
jpAnnotation.add(btnUnderline);
```

Comment: I would suggest trying to use [`ImageIO.read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) over `ImageIcon` as it will throw an `IOException` when something goes wrong, rather the silently failing like `ImageIcon` does

Comment: `btnUnderline.setSize(50, 260);`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement ***or sizing*** of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a little code snippet:

```
btnUnderline.setIcon(
  new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to/UnderlineIcon.gif")));
```

### Brief explanation

Using this statement for loading your image, you don't have to care about the right URL to your file, because you automatically get the correct URL.

This is based on loading the resource from the *class path* and not from the *filesystem path*!

Comment: I would guess that this is what the OP is looking for, but perhaps you'd like to explain why so they understand there mistake ;)

Comment: @PrR3, I used your code but it has error 'The method setIcon(Icon) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Image)'

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` looks for a file on the file system, from what the OP has posted, it looks they might be using embedded resources (files stored within the Jar/Classpath), which is generally a preferred approach.  Just so we can distinguish between the two mechanisms ;)

Comment: [`AbstractButton.setIcon(Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon-javax.swing.Icon-) specifies an `Icon` not an `Image`, so the last part of that, `.getImage()` seems wrong to me..

Comment: @AndrewThompson yeah man thx for your advice. i used it in an extended  context and forgot to remove the transformation step completely ([look here](http://pastebin.com/HxFKBh78))! Sry for that!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
btnUnderline.setIcon( new ImageIcon( "C:\\YourFolder\src\MyPackage\UnderlineIcon.gif" ) );
```

If of course you're using Windows. Alternatively you can move the gif to the same directory as where you're executing your code from.

Comment: Using an absolute reference to any external file is a bad idea, this will break the programs ability to execute on other computers...